# How do I display a title on mouse hover on an angularjs expression rendered on html page?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a section in my HTML page as follows:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="patient={firstName:'John',lastName:'Doe'}">
    <p>{{ patient.firstName}} | {{ patient.lastName }}</p>
</div>
```

It is displayed in the form of a tile and needs to display the rendered text on mouse hover in a tooltip.

I have used `text-overflow: ellipsis`, in my CSS to display `(...)` in case the text length exceeds my span size.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a snippet of your html code?  Also, you may want to consider using an angular directive to render the tooltip.  If you don't want to write your own, angular has a great UI toolkit that includes a tooltip directive.
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tooltip

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will help you..

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover